# Eclipse plugin external Resources

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I've got a eclipse plugin ready, but now i need a way to save some files outside the jar, this files will xml and txt.

My question is how to acess them and where i put them so i can test the plugin without exporting the plugin to the eclipse plugins folder.
 I have already tried to put them in a folder inside the project but they don't appear in the output.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need files to be outside of the plugin JAR during runtime then the trick is to just extract them from there. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8509612/150166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a plugin that you are exporting and you have added additional files to it, make sure that in the build.properties file, those files are identified. To do this, open the plugin manifest and click on the Build tab and check the files you wish to have exported.