# How to Reference Jar File Location at Runtime

Tags: java, jar, reference

I need to reference some jar files when executing a Java program. The problem is that those jar files will not be in a standard location ever. That means when the Java program starts up I need to find out where those jar files are and update any references in the Java program. I have no idea how to do this though.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Scenario:**
I have a Process A (written in .NET) that will start Process B (a Jar file). Process B needs to reference tons of Jar files(250MB). The problem is that the location of the jar files will change.

Several Examples:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\TestProgram 
D:\OtherProgram 
E:\Program Files\ThirdLocation
```

So, either Process A or B will read the registry (on a Windows Server) to find out where the Jar files are located. Then Process B needs to "magically point all the references in the code to those jar files".

**Problem:**
The problem is that I don't know how to "magically point all the references in the code to those jar files". I assume I have to dynamically load the jars somehow, or update the references when I start Process B.

I have tried to configure the build path, but I don't think I did it correctly, so it didn't work as expected.

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Have you looked into using Maven for managing dependencies?

Comment: I posted a utility method that may help here. [Finding he path to a jar from a class inside it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508114/finding-the-path-to-a-jar-from-a-class-inside-it/8508874#8508874).

Comment: I posted a utility method that may help here. [Finding he path to a jar from a class inside it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508114/finding-the-path-to-a-jar-from-a-class-inside-it/8508874#8508874).

Comment: The jar files I am referencing is a horrible SDK(Business Objects(SAP)), and I just needed to reference their SDK Jar files. Because of that, from the very little I know about Maven, I don't think it would help, and the other code, from Paul, I don't think will help. Thanks for the suggestions though, they were helpful in pushing me to look at other options. (My final solution in Ravi's post)

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments of the Java runtime (java.exe or javaw.exe) is -cp. It is used to set the classpath as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#options).

The nice thing about Java 6 is that you can use wildcards while setting your classpath. So supposing that you need to load all JARS inside one folder, you can do something like this:

```
-classpath "../lib/*"
```

For the command line, -classpath and -cp are the same thing.

To separate the classpaths, you must use a semicolon. You can easily configure your whole classpath using the wildcards above or, if that doesn't work, then you will need to specify each JAR file manually. Be aware of the [command prompt max length](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) in Windows while doing that.

Comment: What I'm going to end up doing is package the jar files I need with the app, instead of trying to find them on the local machine. Knowing about the class path helped a bit with the problem, but I couldn't get the "*" to pick up all of the jar's properly.

Comment: That's a better solution indeed. You can use something like Maven to do the job for you.